# Curl command to get inventory-id from ansible tower

Tags: curl, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

I need to retrieve the inventory_id for a given project (project_dev is the project name) from ansible tower using curl command

```
curl -X GET -s -k -u "user:password" -vvv  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"organization": 1,"name": "project-dev"}' https://ansibletower.com/api/v2/inventories/"
```

Comment: What's wrong with [tower-cli](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli)? See [Inventory](https://tower-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_ref/resources/inventory.html).

Comment: I am using shell script and need the inventory_id retrieved from ansible tower via automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *`I need to retrieve the inventory_id from ansible tower.`*

A: Use [tower-cli](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli)

> Usage: tower-cli inventory get [OPTIONS] [ID]

Q: *`How to add special character password to tower-cli config?`*

A: Use [tower_cli.cfg](https://github.com/aditosoftware/ansible-tower-cli/blob/master/tower_cli.cfg)

```
$ cat $HOME/.tower_cli.cfg 
[general]
host = http://srv.example.com
username = admin
password = password
verify_ssl = no
```

Comment: How to add special character password to tower-cli config?

Comment: No, I am not asking you to read the doc, my password contains special character and I was unable to add it to tower-cli config. I have figured out how to do that now.

Comment: When I try ```tower-cli inventory get ID```, I get below error and I was also trying to understand how can I pass project_name
```Error: The requested object could not be found.```

Comment: ```tower-cli inventory get -n project_dev | sed -e '1,3d'| sed -e '2d'| awk '/^[0-9]/ {print $1}'``` This command retrieves the inventory_id  for a given project name using tower-cli